# ¿Qué diferencia una voz de origen expresivo de una de origen onomatopéyico?

Tags: etimología, dle, onomatopeyas

Las voces de origen onomatopéyico se forman al tratar de imitar sonidos que oímos y representarlos mediante letras y palabras. En cambio, tenía entendido que las voces de origen expresivo eran las formadas a partir de grupos de sonidos que nosotros pensamos que pueden representar diferentes ideas, sin que estas tengan un referente real.

Un ejemplo lo da Corominas en su diccionario etimológico en la voz *pizpireta*, donde afirma que es de origen expresivo y que el grupo consonántico *psp* puede generar palabras que expresen movimiento. Este grupo daría también origen a *[pispa](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDDHCJv)*, y puede que a la expresión *[pispás](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TDHBi37)*. Voces de origen expresivo serían también *[tonto](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a1laMnE)*, *[mimo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PHPmErj)* y *[chichi](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8iwXb8F)*, según el DLE.

En cambio, el propio DLE cita *[pizpireta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=THOeuuR)* como de origen onomatopéyico, lo que me crea la confusión. También se puede ver que *[chocho](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8wW365h%7C8wY7c3t)* puede ser de origen onomatopéyico o expresivo según su significado. Otro ejemplo sería *[tirria](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZsJxHXs)*, que el DLE cita como de origen onomatopéyico, mientras que Corominas dice que vendría de una interjección *trr* que expresaría despecho, lo que la convertiría en voz expresiva.

Así pues, ¿cuál es la diferencia exacta entre una voz de origen onomatopéyico y una de origen expresivo? ¿Es posible que haya un cierto solape entre ambos tipos, y que algunas voces se puedan catalogar como de ambos tipos según se interprete?

Comment: @walen sí, más que una pregunta de etimología es de "meta-etimología", pero no encontré mejores etiquetas (se aceptan sugerencias). Sobre el ejemplo de "tirria", la cuestión es saber si realmente existe solape entre ambas categorías etimológicas, o si no lo hay pues saber quién se equivoca.

Answer (score 2):

Las "onomatopeyas" son una subclase de "creaciones expresivas":

> Lo que el DCECH define como ‘voz de origen expresivo’ se puede enmarcar en
>   más de una categoría: se trata, por un lado, de voces onomatopéyicas indudables
>   (e.g. *cucú*) o voces que, según Corominas / Pascual, están originadas en el lenguaje infantil (e.g. *coco* ‘gusanillo’); por otro lado, pueden ser voces cuya forma parece remitir a lexemas románicos o indoeuropeos similares, pero cuyo análisis fonético, de acuerdo con las leyes conocidas, parece impedir cualquier relación concreta con aquellos (e.g. *mocho*); igualmente, dado que su forma y sentido parecen sugerir una relación fonosimbólica entre significante y significado, Corominas concluye en muchos casos que las palabras respectivas podrían estar originadas en la intención del hablante de reproducir la impresión acústica, visual o táctil que le produce un cierto fenómeno, objeto o estado.
>
> - [Las ‘creaciones expresivas’ del *Diccionario crítico etimológico
>     castellano e hispánico* en contexto románico e indoeuropeo. Un nuevo
>     (y a la vez antiguo) enfoque](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/RFRM/article/view/61689/4564456548222) (2018)

Answer (score 1):

Me gustaría dejar documentada aquí la respuesta que me ha dado la RAE a esta misma pregunta a través de *Enclave RAE*:

> La cuestión que nos plantea es un poco polémica y no necesariamente existe acuerdo entre los especialistas, como usted supone. En clasificaciones como la mencionada influyen los conceptos de interjección y de onomatopeya, pero, además, debe tenerse en cuenta que algunas interjecciones se clasifican como expresivas.

Y hasta aquí puedo leer... porque no hay más. Vamos, que directamente reconocen que he tocado un aspecto en el que los expertos no se ponen de acuerdo. A continuación me recomiendan la lectura de los apartados [32.3-32.4](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SnOlXCWzktzKCTlD) y [32.7](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pnwTYRsjmgQkPKYQ) de la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española*, que tratan, respectivamente, de los aspectos fónicos y gráficos y las interjecciones y onomatopeyas, de los aspectos sintácticos de las mismas, y de las interjecciones expresivas o sintomáticas.

Se despiden recordándome que mi pregunta se aparta del ámbito del servicio (cuestiones relativas al uso correcto de la lengua española) al ser de índole teórica.

Comment: @walen sí, es curioso que aun cobrando por el servicio no acepten consultas más allá del mismo ámbito con el que responden en Twitter gratuitamente. Eso sí, he notado que en _Enclave_ tienden a pasar más la mano, a juzgar por algunas preguntas que he visto respondidas usando el buscador de consultas.